tengo un problema de codigo la llamada al metodo no esta definida y estoy perdido
<?php 

class peliculaModel{
    private $conexion;

    public function __construct($db) {
        $this->conexion = $db;
    }

    public function registrarPeliculas( $id_compañia, $titulo, $idioma){
        $sql = "INSERT INTO peliculas ( id_compañia, titulo, idioma) VALUES (:id_compañia, :titulo, :idioma)";
        $stmt = $this->conexion->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindParam(':id_compañia', $id_compañia);
        $stmt->bindParam(':titulo', $titulo);
        $stmt->bindParam(':idioma', $idioma);
        return $stmt= $this->execute(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }

    public function obtenerPeliculas($id_peliculas) {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM peliculas WHERE id_peliculas = :id_peliculas";
        $stmt = $this->conexion->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindParam(':id_peliculas', $id_peliculas);
        $stmt->execute();
        return $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }

    public function eliminarPeliculas($id_peliculas) {
        $sql = "DELETE FROM peliculas WHERE id_peliculas = :id_peliculas";
        $stmt = $this->conexion->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindParam(':id_peliculas', $id_peliculas);
        return $stmt->execute();
    }

  

    public function actualizarPeliculas( $titulo, $idioma, $id_compañia) {
        $sql = "UPDATE peliculas SET  titulo = :titulo, idioma = :idioma, id_compañia = :id_compañia WHERE id_peliculas = :id_peliculas";
        $stmt = $this->conexion->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindParam(':titulo', $titulo);
        $stmt->bindParam(':idioma', $idioma);
        $stmt->bindParam(':id_compañia', $id_compañia);
        return $stmt->execute();
    }

    public function obCompañia(){
        $sql= $conexion ->query("SELECT * FROM peliculas INNER JOIN compañia ON P.id_compañia= C.id_compañia" );

    }


    public function obtenerCompañia() {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM compañia";
        $stmt = $this->conexion->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute();
        return $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }
}
?>


¿Qué has intentado? ¿Qué errores tienes? Donde está el Ejemplo Mínimo Verificable de lo que has hecho y fundamentalmente parte del código que has utilizado (en texto, no imagen) que se menciona en el [tour] y en [ask]

@PsychoMx te lo ha dicho casi todo en su respuesta, aunque sin explicar el asunto. El código está mal aquí $this->execute(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) porque $this hace referencia a la clase actual peliculaModel y para el ´executedebes usar el objeto$stmtcreado previamente, no la clase actual. EnobCompañiate faltan los alias de las dos tablas, no de una de ellas. Finalmente, convendría que respetes la *convención de nombre*. Por lo general las clases se nombran usandoCamelCase, para tu caso, la clase se llamaría PeliculaModel`...

... Y el método obCompañia debería llamarse  obtenerPeliculasConCompañias, porque es lo que hace, obtener películas con sus compañías. El código funcionará aunque llames a tu método obtenerPaamayimNekudotayim, pero comprender el código es importante, para el propio programador y para otros, en el caso de trabajo en equipo. Finalmente, para evitar el uso de ñ, acentos, etc, que en ciertos casos pueden romper el código, puedes adoptar una convención en inglés, es más breve, más limpia y ayudará en caso de trabajo en equipo. Por ejemplo: getFilmsWithCompany.

Otro apunte: para los métodos que modifican datos, convendría retornar las filas afectadas, en lugar de retornar el resultado del execute(), porque esto te permitirá verificar en el llamador si realmente esa acción ocurrió. Me refiero a los métodos eliminar y actualizar aquí. Si tú retornas $stmt->rowCount(), podrás hacer en el llamador if($instancia->actualizarPelicula(...) > 0) { //Hubo actualización }  else { //No hubo actualización}. ¿Cuál es el punto? Que un update o delete NO depende solamente de que sea true o false, sino de que al menos una fila sea afectada ...

... Por ejemplo, una consulta con un criterio WHERE que no encuentre filas, resultará en un true, porque la ejecución de dicha consulta no levantó ningún error, pero NO actualizará o borrará NINGUNA fila, porque simplemente NO encontró filas para actualizar o borrar. A lo mejor tú escribirás en el llamador un mensaje del tipo Filas borradas o actualizadas correctamente, pero eso no es cierto, porque NO se actualizó / borró ninguna fila. Devolviendo el total de filas podrás mostrar algo del tipo: Se actualizaron / borraron N filas donde N es el valor devuelto por rowCount().

Hay varios errores entre ellos:
Error 1:
/*Cambia esto: */
return $stmt = $this->execute(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 

/* por esto: */
$stmt->execute();

Error 2:

actualizarPeliculas le falta el parámetro $id_peliculas

Error 3:

En obCompañia la consulta está mal formada, cambia $this->conexion por $conexion y te falta el alias para id_compañia. (te recomiendo no usar ñ para definir variables, metodos, etc.)


El colega PsychoMx tiene razon, es pesimo meter letras como ñ, ö, ä, å... etc. en el codigo fuente.
